# What is the bottleneck when I'm downloading something and playing a video?

Tags: networking, video

When I'm downloading a file (torrent) and playing a video, my video will periodically freeze.  The video uses the GPU and barely the CPU, the total CPU usage isn't anywhere near 50% when I'm doing these two activities.

I'm wondering what the bottleneck is, and if there is anything I can do to improve it.  Reducing the download speed didn't seem to help.

Comment: perhaps you should be asking `how to identify the cause of a bottleneck?`  ... where is the video originating?

Comment: both are using the micro sd card

Comment: are you saying that the torrent is downloading to an SD card and the video is playing from the same SD card?

Comment: yes they are both using the same sd card.  Maybe that is the bottleneck?  I'm wondering now if I download to my external drive if it first gets buffered on the sd card.

Comment: No, it would not be.

Comment: @goldilocks The freezing stopped after I started downloading to an external usb ssd and playing from the same external usb ssd. I can do both at the same time.  I couldn't from the onboard micro sd card.  Maybe it is the bus it uses.  Idk.  This should all be easily reproducible by anyone else.

Comment: What I meant was, if you were playing a video off the SD card and downloading a torrent *to an external drive*, the torrent data would not be buffered/cached on the SD card -- which AFAICT re-reading the question and previous comments was what you were asking in comment #4: "if I download to my external drive if it first gets buffered on the sd card" = No, or at least there is no need for that to happen (it's possible, of course, but I doubt very much the relevant software is implemented that way).  Anyway, glad you found a solution.

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for clearing that up.  That is useful info.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually all modern torrent clients use some sort of internal caching to improve performance. If the cache is large, there will be a noticeable slowdown when it expires or is flushed.

Try running your torrent client with `nice` and try setting a smaller cache size with a shorter expiry time. If you primarily use the Pi for downloads, long expiry time is simply counter-productive.

There's also a cache setting in video players, if the bottleneck is the SD card then caching 10 or so seconds of video to RAM should help.

Comment: My transmission-daemon is using a cache size of only 4MB by default.

Comment: Have you tried `nice` nevertheless?

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck was the SD card.  When I used an external USB drive to download and play from, the stutters stopped.